# Start point for study content based video search

Tags: c++, algorithm, computer-vision, video-processing, cbir

I was involved in computer vision development several years, but have never worked with CBIR or video search.
Could you advise me how to start? Articles, algorithms, open source engines (C++).
I want to create video search engine, which can find the video clip among thousands of indexed using a short distorted, scaled, rotated or cutted fragment.

Answer (score 2):

A good start (although 10 years old already) is the work of Sivic and Zisserman: [Video Google](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/vgoogle/), there is more of course: check out anything on the topic in CVPR proceedings and PAMI transactions. For open-source building blocks: check out [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) (Computer Vision) and [Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/) (Search).